# Black star won't absorb the souls of some people

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When killing bandits or forsworn with a empty black star, eight out of ten times, I won't get a soul. The animation will appear and it will look like they are getting soul trapped but the star will remain empty.

From my knowledge the star should absorb every soul but it could be random, is it? If not has anyone else had this problem or is it just me?

Comment: If my answer was correct, would you consider accepting it so other people will have use for it in the future? if it was not helpfull, could you comment why i can edit my answer and so other people will have use for it too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the elder scrolls wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Black_Star)

> *"The Black Star is a re-usable black soul gem. As such, it is able to store black souls, which are always of the Grand level, along with
>   white souls.
>
>   Like other soul gems, it can only hold one soul at a
>   time. Unlike other soul gems, the Black Star is not destroyed after
>   its contents are used - it is simply emptied and can be filled with
>   another trapped soul. **When trapping souls, any compatible soul gem in
>   the inventory will be used before the Black Star.**"*

Considering that you say **you do get** the animation, its most likely that another gem was filled instead of the black star.