# How to fill a black soul gem?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I have to fill this black soul gem for *Falion*, so I killed a few Draugr and used Soul Trap on them within the 60 seconds but it didn't fill it?

I emptied out all of my other empty soul gems and still nothing happened?
Does it have to be a human that I have to kill? I don't think I have long until I'm a 'Stage 4' Vampire?

Comment: A draugr should fill a black sould gem just fine. Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36778/108003

Comment: Have you been able to soul trap anything else before? The process should be the same. What you've written makes it sound like you're casting soul trap after they die, which would be wrong. You have to cast it while they're alive and then kill them within the time limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do Soul Gems work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35221/4797), [Black star won't absorb the souls of some people](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/251646/4797), [How do I know what type of soul a creature has?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36778/4797) and/or [What is the Black Soul Gem for?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36719/4797)

Answer (score 8):

Black soul gems can hold humanoid souls, (and the same souls that white/regular soul gems can hold), while white/regular soul gems can only hold the souls of lesser creatures.

Taken from the [Skyrim wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Soul_Gem_%28Skyrim%29):

> Black souls are those of sentient, humanoid beings such as Imperials,  Argonians, Khajiit and Dremora, while white souls are those of animals and  certain lesser Daedra.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to make weapons with soul trap then just have an empty black soul gem and use the soul trap weapon. You can get the book in Whiterun at the Jarls keep.

Comment: The soul trap spellbook does not allow you to enchant weapons with soul trap.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I should have put "destroy a weapon at the enchanter table to learn the ability for making weapons."

Answer (score 0):

You have to kill a human. Any human, including but not limited to bandits, civillians, and guards meet the criteria. DCShannon is right, but at the same time it wouldn't be a black soul, which is what you actually need. Draugrs are petty and common souls, harder creatures have better souls, and humans have black souls. Each soul corresponds to the soul gem with the same name (I.E. common soul goes in common soul gem, greater soul in greater soul gem, etc.)